# cfqueryparam is acting weird

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I'm having a problem running an update query in coldfusion. I get an error saying Invalid data '' for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_NUMERIC. I know the data is numeric because I output it before the error and it's right. I set the variable like so:

```
<cfset itemID = FORM.itemID * 1> <!--- The * 1 is to force a numeric operation, and
therefore a numeric datatype, and like I said, it outputs right. --->

<!--- This is the line (45) the error says is bad --->
WHERE itemid = <cfqueryparam value="#itemID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC">
```

One weird thing that happens is if I change the cfqueryparam to varchar, I still get the same error!!

```
WHERE itemid = <cfqueryparam value="#itemID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
```

And even weirder, when I completely take out the cfqueryparam and use a number, a new error comes up saying the line BEFORE (44) is bad now:

```
WHERE itemid = 20072 <!--- Changing to this produces a new error on the line before --->

<!--- Line 44, which is also using a cfqueryparam numeric. This new error is the same
as before, but on line 44 now instead of 45. --->
min_qty = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemMinQuantity#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC">
```

Any idea what's going on?

**EDIT** more code...

```
<cfquery name="qUpdateItem" datasource="#thedb#">
UPDATE items_something
SET
    itemdesc = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemDescription#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    room = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemRoom#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    value = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemValue#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC">,
    categoryid = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.categoryID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC">,
    keywords = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemKeywords#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    manufact = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemManufacturer#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    partno = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemPartNumber#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    itemtitle = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemTitle#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    qty = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemQty#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC">,
    assembly_draw_no = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemAssemblyDrawingNo#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC">,
    bin = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemBin#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    shelf = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemShelf#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    min_qty = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemMinQuantity#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC">
WHERE itemid = <cfqueryparam value="#itemID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC">
```

Comment: if you're looking at the coldfusion error and it says "on line X" and on line "X" reads your where clause, don't take that to heart, that's the last line of the sql so any of that query can be a problem. getting the same error when you change that line to varchar would prove that.

Comment: @Travis yes it does have a value. I cfoutput itemID right after I set it, and it was right.

Comment: bleh, you replied before i could delete that comment. lol.  see my last comment.

Comment: @Travis Do you know how I could get the Oracle error code to see specifically what the problem is?

Comment: Run the query from your Oracle IDE (SQL Developer, Toad, etc).

Comment: @phantom42 Can I do that when my code is filled with cf syntax? I can write an SQL statement that works, but I think the issue is that coldfusion code is not working.

Comment: No, you'll have to replace the queryparams with your intended values. If you've got debugging on, you can also wrap your query with a try/catch and then dump the error. You'll find the ORA code in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may not have anything to do with the queryparam.  Oracle errors on the last line of the executing statement (usually a where, group by or order by clause).  If you supply the ORA- error and your table defs that would help.

But the error probably isn't related in any way to the queryparam.  There's something else (identical columns in a join (e.g., the ID column in two tables in the query), missing comma, etc.).

**EDIT:**

Based on the text from the [cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) help page you may want to try CF_SQL_FLOAT or CF_SQL_DECIMAL since CF_SQL_NUMERIC doesn't appear to have a direct correlation to Oracle.  You can check your other columns too.  I don't know if this would explain it but I do seem to remember seeing this in the past.

Comment: You can see it if you wrap the query in a try/catch and dump the catch struct.  Or, as phantom42 responded above, you can run the query (subbing in actual values for the queryparams) and see what Oracle is complaining about.

Comment: most likely cfqueryparam caused some db caching that cleared.  it's amazing what a lunch break can do.

Comment: As long as it's working, sometimes that's the best you can ask for.  It could be that there was compiled class issues too.  I've seen that sometimes class files don't go away, even when it should re-compile them.  Haven't seen it in a long time (maybe not since I moved to 9), but it has happened.  Hey, it's a win for a Monday, right?